# how to return empty array rather than empty object with lodash

Tags: node.js, lodash

I have an object that I return when I have some data returned from query.

```
{
"responseMethod": "Method_Name",
"responseMessage": "",
"responseCode": 200,
"errorCode": "",
"responseData": {}
}
```

What I need if there is no data then it should show like below

```
  {
"responseMethod": "Method_Name",
"responseMessage": "",
"responseCode": 200,
"errorCode": "",
"responseData": []
}
```

I have used lodash.get to convert it but no success. please help

```
lodash.get(result,'result.responseData',[]);
```

The above one not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```js
var foo = {
  "responseMethod": "Method_Name",
  "responseMessage": "",
  "responseCode": 200,
  "errorCode": "",
  "responseData": {}
}
Object.keys(foo.responseData).length === 0 && (foo.responseData = [])
console.log(foo)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @suresh Prajapati